# CakePHP and SimpleTest failing tests from clean install

Tags: cakephp, fatal-error, simpletest

I've just downloaded Cake PHP 1.3, and installed SimpleTest 1.0.1 into the vendors directory. When I run cake testsuite core all I get the following error:

Running core all PHP Fatal error:  `Cannot redeclare class Article in /Users/../cake/tests/cases/libs/model/models.php on line 283`

If I run test groups or test cases individually, many of them fail.

This is a clean install, I've done no development other than the basic configuration setup (security salt, cipherSeed and database config).

Has anyone else had problem, and what did you do to solve it?

I found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cake-php/JOOLAg5wyt8) thread with the exact same question, but it was not resolved or at least the resolution was not posted in that thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, as noted in the [CakePHP 1.3 documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1199/Running-Core-test-cases):

> If you run all of the core tests at
>   once or run core test groups most of
>   them will fail. This is known by the
>   CakePHP developers and is normal so
>   don't panic. Instead, try running each
>   of the core test cases individually.

Lame. Why even bother making core tests if they fail. I just lost a lot of faith in Cake. But this is their answer...